# Ternary operator in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ternary-operator

Hi all I would like to use ternary operator in aspx page. I am having two public variables in my aspx.cs file as follows

```
public string currency = "INR";
public decimal amount = 100;
```

I would like to frame the html tags based on my currency, currently I am doing like this

```
<% if (currency != "INR")
  {%>
     <span>$<%=amount%></span>
  <%}
  else
  { %>
    <span<%=amount%></span>
  <%} %>
```

I would like to do it one line

`<span><% if (currency != "INR") %> $ amout <% : %> </span>`

But I am getting error as `Invalid expression term ':'` so can some one help me if this is possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tenary operator works without an if. It looks as follows:

```
booleanExpression ? trueValue : falseValue
```

But you can't treat ASP.NET like PHP, so you will have to put this in one `<% %>`  wrapper

```
<span><%= (currency != "INR" ? "$" : "") + amount %></span>
```

Comment: I am getting `Invalid expression term ':'` when I execute

Comment: @Dotnet You are missing one more value after <% : %>. You need to provide one more value to make it work.

Comment: `<span><% currency != "INR" ? %>  <% amount : %> $ <% amount %> </span>` still not getting

Answer (score 1):

Remove if from expression

You need to provide one more value after :

```
<span><%= (currency != "INR" ? "" : "Rs.") + amount %></span>
```

Comment: `<span><% currency != "INR" ? %> <% amount : %>$ <% amount %> </span>`

Comment: @Dotnet Please try like this <span><%= currency != "INR" ?  amount  :  amount %></span>

Comment: For some reason using a ternary in this mannercauses the entire aspx file to throw compilation errors for every single object referenced used within, saying that it does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

bytecode77's code looks really awkward. I'd suggest:

```
<span><%= (currency != "INR") ? amount : " " %></span>
```